# UE4 2D Animation have Bug

Tags: 2d, unreal-engine4

I want to make an AI can move randomly, but when AI move it's animation seems so wierd... how to tackle this problem in UE4?

[image: The problem of AI]

I try to delete the z-axis actor location but it was useless. I wonder how to tackle this problem.